# How do I check that Thread.Interrupt() was invoked on my thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Is there any way to check if Interrupt() was called on my thread, similarly to Java's Thread.isInterrupted?

Comment: Please be more specific. In what context are you trying to determine the interrupted state? What have you tried so far? What did that do, and how was that different from what you wanted? Please include [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that clearly shows the scenario you are trying to address and what you want to happen.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, are these requirements due to some new "rules"?

Comment: There are no "requirements". You can post whatever question you want. But everyone else can choose to ignore it, vote it down, whatever. When someone asks you to improve your question, it is to benefit _you_. The "rules" (as you describe it) are not new. They are outlined clearly in the link I already offered, as well as at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, along with a variety of other help center topics on the site. They are long-standing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's anything similar. You'll get an exception in the thread if someone interrupts you and you're blocked (or subsequently block) but that's not quite the same thing as being able to tell if an interrupt is ready for you.

That provides a clue, you could simply block for a short period of time to see if an exception appears.

It might be worth stepping back a bit to examine *why* you think you need this. There may well be a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Exception is raised only when the thread gets into sleep state. I could use a call to Thread.Sleep(0), but it's insanely expensive.

Comment: I'm trying to stop my program on request in a less ugly way then using a termination flag and checking it everywhere.

Comment: @user626528, it's not _just_ sleep, the state in which you'll receive an exception is `waitsleepjoin`, which covers a few things. But `sleep` is probably the easiest to do if you really want to know.

Comment: @user626528: and if you architect your app intelligently, a thread tends to be a main loop cycling through every `x` seconds, so you really only need to check in _one_ place, provided you don't mind the `x`-second latency for shutdown.

Comment: @user626528: _"in a less ugly way then using a termination flag and checking it everywhere"_ -- what's the difference between checking a user-defined flag, and checking an "IsInterrupted" flag?

Comment: @Peter Duniho, because you have to pass this flag around to numerous different objects, and thread state is shared.

Comment: @user626528: C# can _do_ global variables and, contrary to popular belief, they're not evil in _all_ circumstances. You may not need to pass _anything_ around. I would suggest asking another question regarding how to achieve your _requirements,_ without pre-supposing a solution.

Comment: @paxdiablo, static variable flag will stop **all** threads, and what if I need to stop only a specific one?

Comment: @user626528: see my previous comment. All to often people ask "how can I do X with Y?" when the question really should be "how can I do X?". By pre-supposing interrupts, you remove a large portion of the possible solution set.

Comment: @paxdiablo, and what are other possible solutions? Abort() would work, but it's recommended to avoid at all costs.

Comment: @user626528: Global collection of finish flags indexed by thread id. Subclass of thread with its own finish flag. Reducing `x` to the point where it's acceptable. A function callable by _any_ thread to do a quick sleep and see if it's interrupted. Those four popped into my head instantly and I don't doubt they have short-comings but the bottom line remains: C# has no inherent isInterrupted() call (unless someone more knowledgable like JSkeet comes along and proves me wrong), so you'll have to do _something_ :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, that's much better. "Quick sleep" is impossible, though.

Comment: @user626528: _"static variable flag will stop all threads"_ -- absent a good code example, it's impossible to offer specific advice. But, in a well-designed program, a thread is generally represented by some object, usually the object containing the bulk of the code executing in the thread. It would be in that object that a flag would reside, and as an instance member, checking it would be easy. That said, another common pattern is `CancellationToken`, which often is passed into the thread method, and frankly it's not that much of a hassle.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, you need to pass around that thread object, then. Not better in any way.

Comment: @user626528: as I wrote, _"in a well-designed program, a thread is generally represented by some object, usually the object containing the bulk of the code executing in the thread"_. In other words, the "passing" of the object is implicit as the `this` reference. In any case, that's just _one_ example of many alternatives, each of which working best in some specific scenario(s). Take your pick...you have lots of choices. There is no direct equivalent in .NET to the Java flag, and your question is too vague to know what's best in your case.

Comment: @Peter Duniho, a program putting big and complex functionality in a single class obviously is not "well designed". Actually, it's quite the opposite.

Comment: @user626528: "separation of concerns". I'm not suggesting you put "big and complex functionality in a single class". I am suggesting that if your program is so tightly coupled that there's more than a single _simple_ class or two that actually need to know about the cancellation, you have a design problem.